# PHP WooCommerce - How to correctly set values with user roles?

Tags: php, woocommerce, cron, code-snippets

I inherited a PHP project for a client and the developer said: "This script needs to be pulled out to run on a cron every 24 hours." The php script is located in the "Code Snippets" plugin and in WP File manager it looks to be stored in the database.

The goal is to have +3 shirts added on the employees anniversary if their user role is warehouse and +1 if they are just an employee. There might be a syntax error with "user roles" that is causing the issue as well.

```
function user_info_echo() { 
    $user_ID= get_current_user_id();
    $users = new WP_User( $user_ID );
    $role1='';
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
        $role1= $role;
}

    
echo '<li>' . 'First Name' . ' ' . 'Current Date' . ' | ' . 'Hire Date'  .' Shirt Qty</li>' . PHP_EOL;  
foreach ($users as $user) {

    $first_name = $user->user_firstname;
    $last_name = $user->user_lastname; 
    $hire_date = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf-hire-date', true);
    $hire_date = date("m-d", strtotime($hire_date));
    $shirt_quantity = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', true);
    $current_date = date("m-d");

if($current_date==$hire_date && $role1 !=="warehouse")
{
    echo '<li>Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    $shirt_quantity_new = $shirt_quantity +1;
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', $shirt_quantity_new );
} elseif($current_date==$hire_date && $role1=="warehouse") {
    echo '<li>Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    $shirt_quantity_new = $shirt_quantity +3;
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', $shirt_quantity_new );
} else {
    echo '<li>No Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
}   
    
    
}

    
}
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('echo_userinfo', 'user_info_echo');
```

Comment: I can't tell from your edit if you solved the problem or not? Regardless, scheduled tasks generally have no reason to `echo` anything, they should only do work. (The exception is if you are using an output buffer to update some HTML.) At a high level, your code seems correct. To debug further, if needed, separate your logic for the task from the actual scheduling. Make a single page that you can call to debug the logic until it is correct, then remove the debug. To debug the task, change it to hourly and have it do something simple. Once both are working, marry together.

Comment: Also, make sure you are aware of how [WordPress's cron runs](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/), specifically that it "does not run constantly as the system cron does". Instead, you are encouraged to use [system cron to invoke WP's cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/).

Comment: Thanks for the resources Chris. I added a "possible solution" but I am still not sure if the syntax is entirely correct. Also, one of our anniversary employees did not have any shirt quantity added to their total today, which was their hire date, so I am thinking the script is not running once daily.

Comment: Updated script above. I am just going to use shortcode and run the script daily on that page. I am thinking I have incorrect syntax for user roles in the above solution attempt

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I ended up using, thank you for your help:

```
// The shortcode function
    function user_info_echo() { 
    
$users = get_users(array(
    'role' => 'employee'
));
$userwarehouse = get_users(array(
    'role' => 'warehouse'
));

    
echo '<li>' . 'First Name' . ' ' . 'Current Date' . ' | ' . 'Hire Date'  .' Shirt Qty</li>' . PHP_EOL;  
foreach ($users as $user) {

    $first_name = $user->user_firstname;
    $last_name = $user->user_lastname;  
    $hire_date = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf-hire-date', true);
    $hire_date = date("m-d", strtotime($hire_date));
    $shirt_quantity = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', true);
    $current_date = date("m-d");

if($current_date ==$hire_date)
{
    echo '<li>Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    $shirt_quantity_new = $shirt_quantity +1;
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', $shirt_quantity_new );
}else {
    echo '<li>No Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
}   
    
    
}
    //warehouse
foreach ($userwarehouse as $userware) {

    $first_name = $userware->user_firstname;
    $last_name = $userware->user_lastname;  
    $hire_date = get_user_meta($userware->ID, 'wpcf-hire-date', true);
    $hire_date = date("m-d", strtotime($hire_date));
    $shirt_quantity = get_user_meta($userware->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', true);
    $current_date = date("m-d");

if($current_date ==$hire_date)
{
    echo '<li>Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    $shirt_quantity_new = $shirt_quantity +2;
    update_user_meta( $userware->ID, 'wpcf-shirt-quantity', $shirt_quantity_new );
}else {
    echo '<li>No Match ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' ' . $current_date . ' | ' . $hire_date . ' ' . $shirt_quantity . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
}   
    
    
}

    
}
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('echo_userinfo', 'user_info_echo');
```